# How to reduce a number of AJAX requests for a chat?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, keep-alive

I have a chat on my web site and it needs to send many AJAX requests to my server (at least 2 times per second)  in order to check if there are new messages.
Is there a way to reduce the number of requests and reload messages only after they have been posted?
I know that there are no possibility to use sockets (because I can't use flash, java or features of HTML5), but maybe there is some trick dealing with *keep alive* option of HTTP 1.1?

Comment: Use socket.io ;) Which uses websockets and degrades to Ajax if websockets are not available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is an easy way to do this. Effectively, what you do is you increase the timeout for your ajax call to a long timeout (say, 5 minutes). Your server receives the request and then holds it, occasionally checking for new responses. Then, when a new response is warranted, it simply responds to the request, and your client receives the update.

If no response is had within 5 minutes, your client simply timeouts and starts a new ajax request. Your server, if it hasn't responded within 5 minutes, usually then just terminates the held request to get it out of the queue.

Effectively 'server-side' pushing.

Comment: Any links you can provide for examples Tejs?

Comment: No links, but it should be fairly easy to do on your webserver of choice. jQuery's ajax helpers make it easy to set a long timeout.

Comment: @Tejs this technique is [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) or [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)). Probably best to mention that.

Comment: I'm unsure of the name for this technique, but that sounds good =D

Comment: @Tejs comet also provides the "streaming" option. Might want to mention that aswell.

Comment: This is all great, but requires a special server, like Twisted or Tornado. Apache is going to be killed by the amount of waiting threads.